# PSQL: CASE/WHEN could not convert type money to integer

Tags: postgresql, psql, typeconverter

This is the part of the query:

```
(end_date - load_date)*tester_money/(load_date - start_date)
```

Error:

> ERROR:  CASE/WHEN could not convert type money to integer LINE 115:
>   WHEN load_date - start_date > 28 THEN tester_money...

How to make this work?

`tester_money` is of `money` type, while dates are of `date` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of money as a locale dependent text string. You would have to cast it back to numeric in order to do your calculation. `tester_money::numeric`

Check out the following link http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-money.html